# Id problem with Gson and Room in android (Sending json to client)

Tags: android, gson, android-room

I have a problem with Gson and Room with id!
I send data with json(library Gson and JSON) to client (Android app) with Room database implementation , I send client data to android with ids look like :

```
{"map":{"date":"2020-01-15 15:13:42.0","botType":1,"botName":"ds","id":62,"userId":1,"accountKey":"dcab171a-b6cc-4583-b5fc-3e996100725a","status":0}}
```

and I need save exactly save with id in client database but the room generate a new id for this object, what can I fix this issue?
other description about structure :

super class :

```
@Entity
public class SuperBean implements Serializable {
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 public long id;
 @TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
 public Date date = new Date();

 public long getId() {
     return id;
 }

 public void setId(long id) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 public Date getDate() {
     return date;
 }

 public void setDate(Date date) {
     this.date = date;
 }
}
```

And the main class for save to database :

```
@Entity
public class Account extends SuperBean {
//other var...
}
```

Room insert DAO :

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertFromServer(Account account);
```

I use JSON to save data to room database with save id and before do that I clear the account table but the saved object with id that room think needs to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option - 1:** Remove `autoGenerate = true` from `id` in your `SuperBean` entity

```
@Entity
public class SuperBean implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;

    ...
}
```

**Option - 2:** Use another variable like `_id` for **autoGenerate** and keep your desired `id` as it is in your `SuperBean` entity

```
@Entity
public class SuperBean implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long _id;

    public long id;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to autoGenerate For other stuff.

Comment: Then use other variable like `autoId` or `_id`. Check my updated answer

Comment: its like clear the question,  both my server and client use same class for object the extra col effect to database performance

Comment: It's not possible to keep your server `id` with `autoGenerate = true`. You have to follow any one options above. There is no other way. **autoGenerate = true** means you don't have any control over it, SQLite handle it